# Hide submenu behind main nav?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am trying to create a submenu `transition` that is smooth and neat. I am running into some trouble figuring out the best way to approach this.

[Here is the basic menu structure.](http://jsfiddle.net/3dX3T/1/)

What I was is for the submenu to not display and then 'grow' into the main `nav`. [This is how I want the menu to appear whilst hidden.](http://jsfiddle.net/3dX3T/2/) As you can see the header collapses and the submenu is out of sight.

Unfortunately one can not `transition` the `display` property, so I have been trying a few techniques. So far, [this is the closest I have come to the desired result.](http://jsfiddle.net/3dX3T/3/) As you can see this is not optimal, the submenu is just sitting on top of the main `nav`.

Is there any way to hide the submenu behind the main `nav` or a better way to approach this?

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/3dX3T/4/?

Comment: That way^ doesn't transition, that's why I was avoiding using `display:none;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your link to http://jsfiddle.net/3dX3T/2/ is fine just change the code to this:

just add opacity

```
.submenu {
    margin-top: -96px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    opacity: 0; // fade out the element
}

.dd:hover .submenu {
    margin-top: 12px;
    opacity: 1; // fade in the element
}
```